# How to handle AmqpConnectException on pod restart of a spring boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We're using a (reactive) **Spring Boot** app with **RabbitMQ** (Spring AMQP), running on a **Kubernetes** cluster, and lately we noticed some weird behavior in the logs of the application.

When we make a new deploy to the kubernetes cluster we keep getting the following error repeatedly with the correspond exception stack trace until the new pods are up and old ones destroyed:

`Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).`

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:724)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:252)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2163)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2136)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2116)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:407)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:391)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1914)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1895)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1347)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1193)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:660)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1220)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1170)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:640)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:615)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

We can't seem to find the source of the issue.

I'd love if anyone have any ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any luck not logging this exception in a normal 'reconnect' scenario?

Answer (score 2):

`Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` - means the broker can't be reached.

That is normal behavior - the containers are trying to reconnect. You can control the frequency by setting the container's `recoveryBackOff` property. By default, the container will attempt to connect every 5 seconds, using a `FixedBackOff` - you can use a fixed backoff with a longer retry interval, or an `ExponentialBackOff` that will increase the delay each time.

```java
/**
 * Specify the {@link BackOff} for interval between recovery attempts.
 * The default is 5000 ms, that is, 5 seconds.
 * With the {@link BackOff} you can supply the {@code maxAttempts} for recovery before
 * the {@link #stop()} will be performed.
 * @param recoveryBackOff The BackOff to recover.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public void setRecoveryBackOff(BackOff recoveryBackOff) {
```

Comment: Gary, thanks for the answer, but it didn't really solved my problem. On our case we have many queues and when k8s is recycling a pod it kind of close the connection for the old pod or the new pod being added. As we have many listeners, at this moment we get many of these exceptions instantly, the back-off just work for the consecutive connections retries. I tried to create a handler to catch these exceptions but was unsuccessful. the way i see, what i want to do is too uncommon and AMQP is just following it's correct flow by throwing the exception.

Comment: it is not clear why anyone would want to suppress these exceptions, given that they are reporting a problem connecting to the server but we can add a hook to suppress them if you really want to do that; feel free to open a new feature issue on GitHub.